# Use python to reduce number of hits in tabular blast output file

Tags: python, string, search, blast

I have a large blast files in tabular format, for which the number of target sequences weren't limited, so it takes a long time to parse. I want to reduce the number of hits for each query sequence to the first 10.
My python is basic but here's what I have so far

```
import sys

blastfile = open(sys.argv[1],"r")

column1list=[]

for line in blastfile:
    b = line.split()[0]
    column1list.append(b)

uniqcolumn1 = list(set(column1list))

counter = 0

for val in uniqcolumn1:
    #print val
    for line in blastfile:
        #print line
        while counter <= 10:
            if line.startswith(val):
                print line
                counter =+ 1
```

Here's an example of one line of the blast output file, the title of the query sequence is in the first column, in this case 'c8208_g1_i2'

```
c8208_g1_i2 gi|851252702|ref|WP_048131971.1|    79.30   797 165 0   4881    2491    1   797 0.0 1336    acetyl-CoA decarbonylase/synthase complex subunit alpha [Methanosaeta concilii]
```

I think the first part of the code is working OK, up to '
uniqcolumn1 = list(set(column1list))', then I can't get it to print the first ten lines starting with each string in the list.

Comment: More to the point, would you please confirm this is Python 2 and not Python 3?

Comment: @cxw it looks like Python 2 to me. Did he say it was Python 3?

Comment: Yeah I'm using Python 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you are iterating through your file object twice. In Python, file objects work a lot like pointers that read through every line. If you do not move the pointer back, it has nothing to read.

What you would have to do is use the `.seek` function to move this pointer back to the start. For example, let's say you have a `file_to_read.txt` and your `python_script.py`.

**file_to_read.txt**

```
Hello! My name is Bob and I can't think of anything to
put in this file so I'm blabbering on about nonsense
in hopes that you won't realise that this text is not
important but the code in the actually file, though I
think that you wouldn't mind reading this long file.
```

**python_script.py**

```
f = open("file_to_read.txt", "r")
for line in f: print line
for line in f: print line
```

If you were to run this code (and no errors about directories occur) you would only have the `file_to_read.txt` printed once. To solve this, you can just add a `f.seek(0, 0)` in between reading. For example:

```
f = open("file_to_read.txt", "r")
for line in f: print line
f.seek(0, 0)
for lien in f: print line
```

Now, back to your context, you can see how this applies to your code:

```
import sys
# Here is your reading of file
blastfile = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
column1list = []
# Here is the first time you read the file
for line in blastfile:
    b = line.split()[0]
    column1list.append(b)
# Add a line to move back to the start before the
# next reading
blastfile.seek(0, 0)

uniqcolumn1 = list(set(column1list))

for val in uniqcolumn1:
    # Move the counter inside to refresh it after every iteration
    counter = 0
    # Here is the second time you read your file
    for line in blastfile:
        while counter <= 10:
            if line.startswith(val):
                print line
                counter += 1
    # Since you are going to read the file the next iteration,
    # .seek the file
    blastfile.seek(0, 0)
```

**EDIT**

Here is the second half of the code, fixed. You can do it either:

```
for val in uniqcolumn1:
    # Move the counter in
    counter = 0
    # Move the while loop out
    while counter <= 10:
        for line in blastfile:
            if line.startswith(val):
                print line,
                counter += 1
    blastfile.seek(0, 0)
```

The benefit of this is that the for loop terminates earlier, it does not read through the whole file.

The other way is to use this:

```
for val in uniqcolumn1:
    # Move counter in
    counter = 0
    # Remove while statement
    for line in blastfile:
        # Add additional condition to if statement
        if line.startswith(val) and counter <= 10:
            print line,
            counter += 1
        elif counter > 10:
            break
    blastfile.seek(0, 0)
```

The benefit of this is that it looks simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's good to know. However, this still doesn't seem to have the desired output. It seems to just print out the first line for the first query title 10 times.
Is there an issue with the position of the counter?

Comment: @wl284 yes, it seems like it. Just put your counter above my last comment, under `for val in uniqcolumn1`. This will reset the counter for every query title. The code as it is now has quite a lot of bodging to fix errors. I suggest you treat this as learning and use [cxw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37703908/4428725) instead.

Comment: It doesn't change anything unfortunately, I just get the same first line repeated still.

Comment: Same issue, except this time the code doesn't finish. Like it's stuck in an infinite loop or something.

Comment: @wl284 Sorry for the repeated edits. I hope that the recent edit will work.

Comment: Thank you, the first edit didn't work but the second one did.

Answer (score 1):

This one-pass version prints the first 10 of each title in the order they occur in the file:

```
import sys
NUM_TO_PRINT=10     # good practice - use names rather than raw numbers

blastfile = open(sys.argv[1],"r")

titles={};  # an empty dictionary.
    # This will map titles to counts of how many times a line with that title
    # has been printed.

for line in blastfile:
    title = line.split()[0];    # assuming the title is space-delimited, and that the line is not empty
    num_printed = titles.get(title, 0);     # 0 is the default
    if num_printed<NUM_TO_PRINT:
        print line,    # comma because _line_ already has a newline - without the comma, you get a blank line after every printed line
        num_printed += 1
        titles[title] = num_printed     # save where we are
```

Comment: Cheers, that's great and much better than my script, but since I've been trying to get it to work for a while and still don't know why it's not working, could you or anyone tell me how I'd edit the second half of my original script such that it works?